# System of linear equations over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Something like this:
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+4x_4=1\\
x_1+2x_2+4x_3=3\\
2x_1+2x_2+x_4=1\\
x_1+3x_3=2
\end{cases}
$$
over $\mathbb{Z}_5$

I'm fine with solving it in regular $\mathbb{Z}$ but have no idea how to go about this -- perhaps using Guass-Jordan method.

Comment: $\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z$ is a field (even better than a PID like $\Bbb Z$), so all of your usual knowledge of **linear algebra** applies, just with a different type of scalar.

Comment: Do **exactly** what you'd do with that system over $\;\Bbb Z\;$ *except* dividing by some multiple of $\;5\;$ , and at the end right all modulo $\;5\;$ ...

Comment: can $\mathbb{Z}_5$ include say -5?

Comment: You don't know what $Z_5$ is? If you don't you should go back and make sure you do first before going any further. To answer your question, yes it includes $-(1+1+1+1+1)$, but this is equal to $0$ (and you can't divide by $0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss-Jordan is definitely a fine way to go.

- We can add any scalar multiple of an equation to another.
- We can multiply any equation by a non-$0$ constant (that is, by $1,2,3,$ or $4$ *modulo* $5$).
- We can interchange any two equations.

This differs from what you're probably used to, in that "*modulo* $5$" means that we effectively treat $5$ as $0.$ For one thing, this means (for example) that $1+4=0\pmod5,$ so adding $1$ is effectively the same as subtracting $4,$ and vice versa. Note that this also means that $$2\cdot 3=6=5+1=1\pmod{5}$$ and $$4\cdot 4=16=3\cdot 5+1=1\pmod{5}.$$ Hence,

- multiplication by $3$ is effectively division by $2,$
- multiplication by $2$ is effectively division by $3,$ and
- multiplication by $4$ is effectively division by $4.$

For an example to see how this works, let's multiply the second equation by $3$: $$3x_1+6x_2+12x_3=9\\3x_1+(5+1)x_2+(2\cdot 5+2)x_3=5+4\\3x_1+x_2+2x_3=4$$ So, those that already had a factor of $2$ lost a factor of $2,$ while those that didn't gained a factor of $3$ (at least temporarily).